# Javascript class properties - how to assign a function as value to them?

Tags: javascript, function, properties

In my javascript code I have a helper class for formatting objects:

```
class MyHelperClass() {
  get MyStylerFunction() {
    return function(value, index) {
      return "/*some css based on value and index*/";
    };
  }

  get MyFormatterFunction() {
    // similar pattern to MyStylerFunction
  }
}
```

This code is then used by:

```
myObj.table({
  title: ...,
  columns: ...,
  cssfunction: MyHelperClass.MyStylerFunction
});
```

This code doesn't work and gives no error messages on console. As I have no control over the table() function I assume it gracefully fails when the given css getter function is not applicable. However, when I use this:

```
// inside MyHelperClass
MyStylerFunction(value, index) {
  return "/*some css based on value and index*/";
}

// in function table()
...
cssfunction: MyHelperClass.prototype.MyStylerFunction
...
```

It works as expected. If I place the styler function outside the class and just give the name of the function to table(), it also works:

```
// in global namespace
function myStylerFunction(value, index) {
  // you know the drill by now
}

// inside table()
...
cssfunction: myStylerFunction
...
```

The problem is that

1. I don't want to fill the global namespace with junk
2. Using prototype feel clumsy, so I want to avoid that if possible

Is there a way to achieve my goal while keeping the `MyHelperClass.MyStylerFunction` syntax in `table()`?

I have no idea what causes this problem and googling haven't returned any results on how to correctly return function values from class property getters.

Comment: you can make the `MyStylerFunction` method `static`

Comment: Why does `MyStylerFunction` return a function? Without the code of `table` I would guess that it should be: `cssfunction: MyStylerFunction()`

Comment: @NickParsons I don't know how I missed that, it helped.

Comment: @Andreas cssfunction is called every time by the table when a cell's value changes to restyle it based on the new content.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question...

Comment: @Andreas The table() function is added to the prototype of the JQuery object $("<table />"), and it makes a bunch of modifications to it to look and behave a certain way based on the configuration options in the table()'s parameter . One of these modifications is adding an event listener to cell content modification and restyling the cell based on the new content. Since this restyling needs to fire on every modification, the table function takes the reference to the styler function, not just the result of the styler function, hence returning a function.

Comment: @Andreas (continued) Having a parameterless getter property in my class that returns the styler function instead of just having the styler function in the class and getting a reference to that is just my preference.

Comment: Also @NickParsons if you write an answer about making the getter static I will accept it.

Comment: _"Having a parameterless getter property in my class that returns the styler function..."_ - but only if you would call `MyStylerFunction()` - as I've already mentioned in my first comment. Right now you're passing a reference to `MyStylerFunction` but you actually want the its return value - which is also the explanation why the version without `return function...` works

Comment: @Andreas No, I don't. `MyStylerFunction()` is a **property getter**, not a normal function, so writing `MyHelperClass.MyStylerFunction` calls the function and returns its results, not just pass a reference to the function. See: [MDN - javascript get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after are [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) methods. Static methods don't require an instance of your class to be invoked, instead, they can be accessed on the class itself. This can be used for utility functions which you can pack away into a helper class such as your `MyHelperClass`. You can also use static getters, which allows you to run code upon accessing the static method.

```
class MyHelperClass {
  static get MyStylerFunction() {
    return function(value, index) {
      return "/*some css based on value and index*/";
    };
  }

  static get MyFormatterFunction() {
    // similar pattern to MyStylerFunction
  }
}
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
myObj.table({
  title: ...,
  columns: ...,
  cssfunction: MyHelperClass.MyStylerFunction
});
```

As `MyStylerFunction` is `static`, you can access it as a property of the class itself. Moreover, as it's a getter (`get`), you don't need to invoke it like a normal function/method, instead, it will automatically be invoked, returning the function you specified to be returned.